# Is there a way to retrieve invalid Ethereum based tokens that were sent to MyEtherWallet?

Tags: myetherwallet

I am in desperate need of help!
I have accidentally sent InvestFeed tokens ($ift) to my MyEtherWallet, which appears to be unable to hold those tokens. Is there any way for me to get these tokens back?
I already contacted the support of the exchange from which i sent the IFT tokens. Their response was:

> You may be able to recover these yourself though by importing the private key from your IFT into your ETH wallet. If you have a look online you should be able to find instructions on how to do this.

I'm afraid they misunderstood me, as i have no idea what this particular support member is talking about.

I have searched the internet for a while now to find a solution to this problem and finally decided to ask in a forum.

Please apologize if this isn't the forum for these types of questions.

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm understanding your question as, "how do I send tokens (not listed on MEW) out of a wallet that was generated from MyEtherWallet?", then this is how:

1. Go to MyEtherWallet, click on the "Contracts" tab.
2. In "Contract Address", paste in the token contract address.
3. In "ABI / JSON Interface", paste in the token contract JSON ABI.
4. Click "Access" button.
5. In the dropdown under "Read / Write Contract", select the "transfer" method.
6. In the "_to address" field, set the wallet address you want to send to.
7. In the "_value uint256" field, set the amount of tokens you want to send to.
8. Import your using your private key in the "How would you like to access your wallet?" section.
9. Click on the "WRITE" button.
10. Confirm transaction.

Answer (score 0):

MyEtherWallet will not load tokens balances automatically. In the 'Sent Ether & Tokens' page there's a button 'Load Token Balances', press it and wait a little , a list of available token with their balances should appear. Now the drop-down button next to the "Amount to Send" will now let you select Ether or a token.

IFT is in the list of supported tokens by MyEtherWallet, but in the case your token is not you can add a custom token to the list. You can use https://etherscan.io/tokens to search token address, symbol and decimals required in for MyEtherWallet.